# How to insert PHP loop into a div that was created by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

I have looped through the $elements 6 times to create 6 identical containers for each service a company offers. I'm trying to put the "if while" loop at the bottom of the php inside the $element4 'overlay' div. The "if while" loop calls the service title from the MySQL database and displays it on the webpage. I have tried pasting the php code directly between the div tags, I have tried leaving it where it is, I have tried putting the "if while" loop in its own file and putting the include statement between the 'overlay' div tags. Nothing is working. With previous attempts, I have been able to get the h3 tags to populate in the wrong spots in the DOM, but I can't get them where I want them for some reason. Can you please tell me how I can get the output of the "if while" loop to display in the "overlay" div?`

```
  $element = "<div class='service'>";
  $element2= "<div class='img_container'>";
  $element3= "<img class='service_img'/></div>";
  $element4= "<div class='overlay'></div>";
  $element5= "<div class='service_details'></div></div>";
  $count = 6;
  foreach( range(1,$count) as $item){
      echo $element, $element2, $element3, $element4, $element5;
 
  }
 
  ?>
 
 <?php
 
 if($resultCheck > 0){
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 echo "<h3 class='service_title'>" . $row['service_title'] . "<br>" . "</h3>";
 }}
 
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you add the "expected" HTML/output? Just 1 or 2 elements would be fine. This could help understand what structure you're trying to achieve

Comment: Why is this two separate loops to begin with? If your database query returns six records, and you want to create six "blocks" of HTML out of that - then this should be _one_ loop, not two that both iterate six times independently.

Comment: And `echo $element, $element2, $element3, $element4, $element5;` inside the loop, would better be replaced with this syntax to begin with, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: The answer @Rylee provided does exactly what I was looking for! 
This is my first time trying to loop through container creation and data pulls with PHP, and I didn't realize I could use one loop for everything. 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See Refactored Further Below**

To include that foreach loop on EACH service, you could adjust your code to look something like this:

```php
<?php

$element = "<div class='service'>";
$element2 = "<div class='img_container'>";
$element3 = "<img class='service_img'/></div>";
$element4 = "<div class='overlay'></div>";
$element5 = "<div class='service_details'></div></div>";
$count = 6;

// this will end up with the title BEFORE the service element
//     <h3 class="service-title">...</h3>
//     <div class="service">...</div>
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<h3 class='service_title'>" . $row['service_title'] . "<br>" . "</h3>";

            // the below loop is going to create 5 `<div class="service">...</div>`
            // for EACH $row
            foreach (range(1, $count) as $item) {
                echo $element, $element2, $element3, $element4, $element5;
            }

            // you may want to instead want to echo directly
            // echo $element, $element2, $element3, $element4, $element5;
        }
    } ?>
</div>
<?php

// ... rest of code
```

**Refactored**

From reading you description, I think what you're after is something more like this:

```php
<?php
// refactored
// this format will include the title INSIDE the service element
//     <div class="service">
//         <h3 class="service-title">...</h3>
//         ...
//     </div>
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <div class="service">
                <h3 class="service_title"><?php echo $row["service_title"]; ?></h3>
                <div class="img_container">
                    <img class="service_img" />
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="service_details"></div>
            </div>
    <?php }
    } ?>
</div>
<?php

// ... rest of code
```